# Applying Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury to obtain rank 2 update

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

I was reading Nocedal and Wright, and it is stated that one may use the Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury formula 
$$(A+ YGZ^*)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}Y(G^{-1}+Z^*A^{-1}Y)^{-1}Z^*A^{-1}$$

On the hessian $H_{k+1}$ inverse approximation from the BFGS:
 $$ H_{k+1}=  (I - \gamma s_k y_k ^T)H_k(I-\gamma_k y_k s_k^T) + \gamma_k s_k s_k^T$$

To obtain an update formula for the Hessian $B_{k+1}$ for the BFGS:

$$B_{k+1} = B_k - \frac{B_ks_ks_k^T B_k}{s_k^TB_k s_k } + \gamma_k y_ky_k^T $$

Where the setting here is $\gamma_k = \frac{1}{y_k^Ts_k}$ and $H_k = B_k^{-1}$ and $H_k$ and $B_k$ are positive definite symmetric matrices.

My issue is that I do not see how to apply the Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury formula.
What I see is that I want 
$H_{k+1} = A+ YGZ^*$ and that would give me $B_{k+1}$

Then the question is what is $A$, $Y$, $G$, and $Z$. My thoughts are that $A \not = \gamma_k y_ky_k^T$ as that is singular. Thus that leaves $A = (I - \gamma s_k y_k ^T)H_k(I-\gamma_k y_k s_k^T)$, but that is a mess to invert and when I tried it I did not get anything resembling the desired expression and also then what do I define $G,Y,Z$ to be?

Comment: Introduction to Optimization, Zak, Chong, pg. 214.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: write the RHS (I will skip the index $k$) as
$$
H-\gamma sy^TH-\gamma Hys^T+\gamma^2sy^THys^T+\gamma ss^T=
H+\gamma\begin{bmatrix}s & Hy\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1+\gamma y^THy & -1\\-1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}s^T\\y^TH\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Can you finish now?