# How can I show this? (Use Sherman-Morrison formula to obtain an expression for the inverse of a matrix)

Tags: numerical-methods

I have made several attempts to prove what is asked in the image below. I need to use the Sherman-Morrison formula to check that the inverse of the H_{k+1}  matrix can be obtained by the last formula.

[image]

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2785485/applying-sherman-morrison-woodbury-to-obtain-rank-2-update

Comment: whpowell96 I looked at that post but I still can't finish the proof, Could you please help me?